# Run JSX Preprocessor and use ES6 Syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I followed this guide here

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

And am currently using this command to compile my jsx

`npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod`

Unfortunately, I am unable to use ES6 syntax such as

`import MyComponent from 'MyComponent';`

It is not converting this to ES5 syntax and thus I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
"

Comment: Can you provide your config file for `babel`, please?

Comment: You may want to consider using the 'require' syntax in place of the import. const MyComponent = require("MyComponent");

Comment: *It is not converting this to ES5 syntax* - there's no ES5 syntax for import, unless this is modular environment (Node). Babel is supposed to be used together with a bundler (Webpack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Babel is a transpiler converting your JSX and ESNext (ES6 and above) to ES5 which makes even old browsers understand your code. However, it does not have bundling capability, meaning it does not get contents of the file imported and ship all your code in one file. For that, you need to use a bundler like Webpack.

Configuring Webpack might be tedious, I suggest you to use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to use Webpack and Babel pre-configured.

When you are done building your app, in order to ship it to your current website, you can simply replace root with the id of the element in your website inside **index.js**.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then run **npm run build** to create files for deployment inside build folder. From there, simply copy bundle.js and include it in your website.

I hope this helps!